# Gauss Law in Arbitrary dimensions

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, gravity, gauss-law

What is the Gauss law in any arbitrary dimension "n" and how can one derive it?

Comment: c.f. Zwiebach, Intro to String Theory ch. 3.

Answer (score 2):

Whether by Gauss law, you mean the dependence of the electrostatic (gravitystatic) potential $\phi(x)$, created by some source on the distance from the source (located at the origin), then you start from the equation for the Green's function of the Laplace operator $\Delta$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$:
$$
\Delta \phi(x) = q \delta(x)
$$
After the Fourier transform one gets:
$$
k^2 \phi(k) = q \Rightarrow\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^{n} k}{(2 \pi)^{n}} \frac{q \ e^{i kx}}{k^2}
$$
This integral in dimensions $n \geqslant 3$ gives a power law decay for the potential:
$$
\phi(x) = \frac{C q}{|x|^{n-2}} \qquad C = const
$$
For the $n = 2$ case the Green function gives a logarithm:
$$
\phi(x) = C q \ln\frac{|x|}{|x_0|}\qquad C = const
$$
And for the $n=1$ case ($\theta(x)$ is the Heavyside function):
$$
\phi(x) = q x \theta(x)
$$
The static for general distribution of charges follows from the principle of superposition.

Answer (score 0):

The general law is called Stokes' theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem. In three dimentions, Stokes' theorem has two special forms: the Stokes–Cartan theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Stokes_theorem, and Gauss's theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem.